# No resource found error after converting Android Studio project to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am using Android Studio project in Eclipse. What I did was i created an Android project in Eclipse, copied all the stuffs in java folder to src folder of Android Eclipse project. Also copied res and Manifest to Android eclipse project.

I am now getting an error in values folder like `No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'`.

Could anyone tell me what would be the problem? And how I could solve this?

Comment: Do you have updated ADT and latest SDK version installed in the system? if you dont have then please install those.

Comment: Yeah i have done it...

Comment: It seems your issue has been resolved.

Comment: No..I have the latest SDK version and also updated ADT. Still it is not resolved

Comment: With which android version are you compiling your project? It should be latest version.

Comment: I am compiling with Android 6.0(23)